# How does one average complex exponents?

Tags: average

I have a huge equations system and in some of them I have to average < > some terms. 
Let's assume that I have terms like $$A(r, t) \mathrm{e}^{i \tau},$$ where $i$ is complex unit.
Now I have to average it by $t$. How can I do it in general form since I do not know the exact form of $A(r, t)$ ?

What is the result of    $$ < A(r, t) \mathrm{e}^{i \tau}> =?$$

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT ONE**

$\tau$ and $t$ have nothing in common in this case

**EDIT TWO**

By averaging by $t$ I mean the standard procedure. Let's say we have to average $sin (t)$ on some interval $[0, T]$. It takes the following form:
$$\frac{1}{T-0} \int_0^T sin(t) dt = - \frac{cos(T) - cos(0)}{T} = \frac{1 - cos(T)}{T}  $$

**EDIT THREE**

Following the formal logic, complex amplitude can be represented in the form of:

$$A(r, t) = \rho \mathrm{e}^{i t} = \rho [cos(t) + i sin (t)] $$ and then simply integrate over the interval $[0, T]$: 
$$<A(r, t)> = < \rho [cos(t) + i sin (t)] > = \frac{\rho}{T} [\int_0^T cos(t) dt + i \int_0^T sin(t) dt ]= \frac{\rho}{T} [sin(T) + 1 - cos(T)]$$

and that shoud be an answer, right ..?

What is confusing me (well I probably look like a funny clown now) is my talk with my scientific supervisor. He said that in our case averaging procedure has to be a simple complex conjugation.. Am I missing something here? I do not see a sign of conjugation here..

Comment: What's the relationship between $\tau$ and  $t$?

Comment: I don't know what those angle brackets mean. What would you mean by something simpler, like $\langle t^2\rangle$, or $\langle\sin t\rangle$?

Comment: I’m sorry I didn’t put it clear.. angle brackets mean averaging procedure

Comment: Yes, but *what* averaging procedure? What would you mean by the average of $t^2$? or of $\sin t$?

Comment: OK, so you've defined averaging *over an interval*. Now, what interval do you have in mind for your original question?

Comment: By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment, you must put @Gerry in it.

Comment: @Gerry thank you very much for your clarification and inducing questions. Please, see Edit three

Comment: I don't know what your supervisor means. It looks like you are treating $\rho$ as a constant, independent of $t$ – is that right?

Comment: @Gerry Yes, $A(r,t)$ has two functional dependency, $\rho(r) $ and time dependency goes to exponents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104511/discussion-between-john-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. Anyway, I don't think I have anything more to contribute here, just to repeat that I'm mystified by your supervisor's statement.

Comment: @Gerry, am I right to think, that if we average by $\tau$ then we get zero as the result of averaging ?

Comment: That would depend, John, on what you average over.

Comment: @Gerry, brilliant! I am sorry I did not say at once. If we average $A \mathrm{e}^{i \tau}$ over period $[0, 2 Pi]$

Comment: I probably confuse you here, but $\tau$ and $t$ are different time. The first one is "fast" pulsating time, the second one is "slow" meantime. This concept comes from perturbation theory, where you can define different time scales. And as far as I understand, if we average by $\tau$ over a period and we average periodic functions, so it must be zero

Comment: Not every periodic function has average zero over a period, but $e^{i\tau}$ does.